# Generic collection looping through for loop

Tags: java

I'm having an issue looping through my generic collection. Although my class doesn't show any compiling errors directly, the IDE (Netbeans) is showing an error on the the class icon within the project tree saying "Error parsing file". Any help would be appreciated.

My code

```
public abstract class AutocompleteCacheImpl<E> implements AutocompleteCache {

    public void store(Collection<E> es) {
        for(E e : es) {
            store(e);
        }
    } 

    public void store(E e) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

interface

```
public interface AutocompleteCache<E> {

    public void store(Collection<E> es);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> public class AutocompleteCacheImpl<E> implements AutocompleteCache

This is wrong, because the AutocompleteCache interface is also generic.

Try this:

```
public abstract class AutocompleteCacheImpl<E> implements AutocompleteCache<E>
```

Also, the keyword `public` should come before the keyword `abstract`

Comment: Doesn't **have** to come, it's only convention.

Comment: Fair enough, but still, fix it before we all go insane ;-)

Comment: I fixed it! interestingly enough it was taught that way in my java class. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the generic type (`AutocompleteCache` ==> `AutocompleteCache<E>`) to let the compiler know that the E in `AutocompleteCacheImpl` is the same as the E in `AutocompleteCache`:

```
public abstract class AutocompleteCacheImpl<E> implements AutocompleteCache<E>
```

Comment: Great Catch, can't believe I missed that. Thanks